# How to prove $f(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}C_{2n+k}^{n}C_{n-1+k}^{n-1}\equiv1\pmod2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients

Prove that $$f(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n+k}{n}\binom{n-1+k}{n-1}\equiv1\pmod2,\quad\forall n\in N^{+}$$

I have tried:

By Lucas TH, we have $f(2n)\equiv f(n)\pmod 2$, but $$f(2n+1)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n+1+k}{n}\binom{n+k}{n}\pmod 2.$$ Then, a little hard to induce it on $n$.

Comment: what about induction on the original statement?

Comment: also your notation is a bit confusing. I found out from wikipedia that both $C_n^k$ and $C_k^n$ are valid. but using $\binom n k$ is unambiguous.

Comment: Have you try to obtain the relation between the terms in the summation for $2n$ and $2n+1$ ? Let $$\binom{2n+1+k}{n} \binom{n+k}{n}=\alpha \binom{2n+k}{n} \binom{n-1+k}{n-1}$$ and find out $\alpha\pmod2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the hockey-stick identity, write
$$
{2n+k \choose n} = {2n+k \choose n+k} =\sum_{i=0}^{n} {n+i+k-1 \choose n+k-1}.
$$
Then,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n {2n+k \choose n}{n+k-1 \choose n-1} \\
=\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{i=0}^n {n+i+k-1 \choose n+k-1}{n+k-1 \choose n-1}\\ = \sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{(n+i+k-1)!}{(n+k-1)!i!}\cdot \frac{(n+k-1)!}{(n-1)!k!}
= \sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{(n+i+k-1)!}{(n-1)!i!k!}\\
= \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(n+2k-1)!}{(n-1)!(k!)^2} + 2\sum_{0\le i<k\le n}\frac{(n+i+k-1)!}{(n-1)!i!k!}\\
\equiv \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(n+2k-1)!}{(n-1)!(k!)^2} = \sum_{k=0}^n {n+2k-1 \choose n-1}{2k \choose k} \pmod 2.
$$
For $k\ge 1$, ${2k \choose k}$ is even, so 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n {2n+k \choose n}{n+k-1 \choose n-1}  \equiv 1 \pmod 2,
$$
as required.